# @update:modelValue disables field rule validation

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Given the following component consuming a Vuetify `v-text-field`

```
<script setup lang="ts">
const props = defineProps<{
  fieldValue: unknown;
}>();

const emit = defineEmits<{
  (e: "update:modelValue", newValue: unknown): void;
}>();
</script>

<!-- This validates -->
<!--
<template>
      <v-text-field
        label="label"
        :rules="[ v => !!v || 'Field is required' ]"
        :model-value="fieldValue"
      />
</template>
-->

<!-- This does not validate -->

<template>
      <v-text-field
        label="label"
        :rules="[ v => !!v || 'Field is required' ]"
        :model-value="fieldValue"
        @update:modelValue="emit('update:modelValue', $event)"
      />
</template>
```

The problem is that when I attach a listener to `@update:modelValue` the field rules don't work anymore ( I can clear the field and nothing happens ). When I remove `@update:modelValue` the field rules are working fine.

[Reproduction link](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Is something wrong with the code or is it a bug?

Answer (score 0):

The `:modelValue` prop and `@update:modelValue` event is an expanded form of `v-model` which is missing in your example.

So, use `v-model` in your `App.vue`, like this-

```
<MyField v-model.field-value="msg" :field-value="msg" />
```

**Edit---**

As per your comments, if you cant use `v-model` then you can follow [this guide](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html) from the documentation, and use it like this-

`App.vue-`

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <MyField :field-value="msg" @update:fieldValue="doSomething"/>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>
<script setup>
  import { ref } from 'vue'
  import MyField from './MyField.vue'
  
  const msg = ref('Hello World!')
  
  const doSomething = (event) => { console.log(event) }
</script>
```

`MyFiled.vue-`

```
<script setup lang="ts">
  const props = defineProps<{
    fieldValue: unknown;
  }>();
  
  const emit = defineEmits<{
    (e: "update:fieldValue", newValue: unknown): void;
  }>();
</script>
<template>
  <v-text-field
    label="label"
    :rules="[ v => !!v || 'Field is required' ]"
    :model-value="fieldValue"
    @input="$emit('update:fieldValue', $event.target.value)"
    @blur="$emit('update:fieldValue', $event.target.value)"
    ></v-text-field>
</template>
```

[Working demo](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That works but would you mind explaining why? Which code is redundant then?

Comment: the demo link is missing ( or broken )

Comment: Added the link.

Comment: so it seems I don't even need the `emit` anymore. Are there any other solutions for this to keep the events? Because this component shoud emit on input and on focus leave

Comment: Yes, no need. If `v-model` is attached to the parent component then the parent component is eligible to listen to the `@update:modelValue` event itself and this is what I mentioned that how `v-model` expands.

Comment: unfortunately this solution doesn't work for me because I can't use the `v-model`. The `field-value` prop is assigned like so `myMap.get(fieldId)?.value`

Comment: I have a doubt if you can't use `v-model` then what is the purpose of `:model-value` and `@update:modelValue`? In that case, you can simply pass the props and use a custom event like input and blur to pass the data to the parent component.

Comment: Please look at the edited answer if it helps.

Comment: yes, I could rename the emitted event but I don't think there should be a difference between `@update:model-value` and `@input`. The problem is that the validation is still broken in my app ( and in the question example ). Yes, it works in your example but I can't figure out why it doesn't work in my examples